# Having rand2() function build rand5()

Tags: probability, computer-science, random

I was asked this question long time ago. Having a function $rand2()$ (in any computer language, "rand" means random) which returns $0$ or $1$ (two values only) with a uniform distribution, i.e. $$P(rand2()=0)=P(rand2()=1)$$
compute the function $rand5()$ which returns $0,1,2,3$ or $4$ with uniform distribution, i.e. $$P(rand5()=0)=P(rand5()=1)=P(rand5()=2)=P(rand5()=3)=P(rand5()=4)$$

I have an answer: use voting to promote each $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\} = L_0$ ($L$ means level) to the next level $L_1$, depending on whether $rand2()$ returns $0$ (not promoted) or $1$ (promoted). If none is promoted, start again, until at least one such $k$ is promoted. At the end of this iteration we obtain $L_1 \subseteq L_0$. Do the same with $L_1$ to obtain $L_2 \subseteq L_1 \subseteq L_0$. And so on, until we reach some level $L_n$ containing only one element. That element is returned as the value for $rand5()$.

This seem to have a uniform distribution, because every element is given an equal chance. But I have a problem with the maths for proving this.

E.g. $k\in L_0$ being promoted to level $p$ means $$P(k\in L_p)=\frac{1}{2^p}$$

$k\in L_0$ not reaching level $p$ means $$P(k\notin L_p)=1-\frac{1}{2^p}$$

$k\in L_0$ "wins" at level $p$ means $$P(L_p=\{k\})=\frac{1}{2^p}\cdot \left ( 1-\frac{1}{2^p} \right )^4$$

$k\in L_0$ "wins" (at any level $>0$) means $$P(rand5()=k)=\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}P(L_p=\{k\})$$
which, using MathWolfram, happens to be equal to $0.289400...$, not the expected $0.2$. I believe I missed the "If none is promoted, start again, until at least one such $k$ is promoted" part in my calculations. But I am a bit lost trying to inject it into the final calculations.

Any help is much appreciated. Or even a better and more efficient algorithm, with less calculations involved.

Comment: Just generate 3 bits, and restart if the value is $\ge 5$.

Comment: The idea is really just to take a uniform distribution on some other set that you can sample from using d2 rolls, and then map about a fifth of that set to each category, restarting if you are outside all 5 parts. So one way to do that is to generate one d5 by rolling 3 d2s and restarting if the rolls represent 6,7, or 8. This fails 3/8 of the time. By doing 5 rolls, you can generate 2 d5s, failing 7/32 of the time. This is faster for generating 2 d5s, because on average the time taken is 32/25 instead of 16/5. Even better is to roll 7 d2s, successfully generating 3 d5s 3/128 of the time.

Comment: It isn't easy to do much better than that (you are essentially looking for powers of 5 which are not too far from the next largest power of 2).

Comment: Choosing $4$ bits is pretty good.  As $15$ is divisible by $5$, this  only fails $\frac 1{16}$ of the time.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about multiples of 5 which aren't powers of 5 for some reason.

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/570/generating-uniformly-distributed-random-numbers-using-a-coin

Comment: Per @leonbloy 's comment, the optimal scenario uses $\log_2(5)$ which is slightly less than $2.322$ flips per number that you want to generate. So the approach of generating 3 numbers at a time that I suggested before is actually quite good because you generate $7$ bits of entropy and actually use $\log_2(125) \approx 6.966$ of them.